# Update values in fragment without recreating it

Tags: android, android-fragments, bundle, state, fragmenttransaction

I have two fragments eg. **FragA** and **FragB**. FragA has a RecyclerView whose item click redircets the user to the FragB. In FragB user updates a value, that needs to be set to a TextView in FragA. But I do not want to lose the state of FragA

I do the following to switch fragments.

```
Fragment fragment = new FragB();
fragment.setArguments(bundle);
FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.home_frame, fragment, m_userName).addToBackStack(null);
fragmentTransaction.commit();
```

In FragB, I create a bundle with the updated information :-

```
FragA mFragA = new FragA ();
Bundle args = new Bundle();
args.putParcelable("UpdatedText", "SomeText");
mFragA .setArguments(args);
getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().remove(this);
getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.container, mFragA).commit();
```

In the above case, the state of FragA remains the same, but none of the methods are called since the Fragment is not recreated. Hence the textview value is not updated.

How can I update the value of the TextView in FragA with information from FragB along with maintaining the state of the FragA?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: are this fragments visible at the same time?

Comment: @Lucem no they are not. So basically, I have a recycler view in FragA whose item click opens the FragB. So if the user has scrolled the recycler view to item 10 to open FragB, hitting back button on FragB should get him back to position 10 of the recycler view

Answer (score 0):

you have to create a class that contains a string and you create an instance of this class in the main activity and you call it in the fragment B to initialize it with the UpdatedText for example you do
class.setTextUpdate ("new text") and in the fragmentA you do class.getTextUpdate

Comment: Hi. Can you show me an example of the same? Where do I call the instance in FragA since none of the methods are being called if I add the fragment instead of replacing it?

Answer (score 0):

Proper way:
Basically you have to properly update your POJOs properly. Use an interface communicate this change back to activity and then from activity update your changes to the recyclerview in Frag A with notifyitemchanged.

Alternate way:
Use an eventbus. There are quite a few libraries for this and you have native event bus too.

[Otto](http://square.github.io/otto/) is one of it. easy to integrate.

Comment: Hi. From which method of the FragA should I call the notify item changed? None of the methods are being called as I am not replacing the fragments but adding and removing them

Comment: Not from Frag A. Create a method in Frag A which inturn calls the notifyitemchanged in the adapter. From Activity call that method using the instance of Frag A.

Comment: Which method of the Activity will be called when I hit back on FragB? Sorry I get really confused with the fragmentation

Comment: I did what you suggested, but when I try pass the updated values from my activity class to FragA, the view returns as null

Comment: which view the instance of Frag A?